# Question about quantum mechanics formalism

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

Are degenerate states stationary in quantum mechanics?  I know that stationary state means single wavefunction corresponding to single energy. But, what will be in the case of several wavefunctions corresponds to single energy (e.g. degenerate states). are All of them  stationary in that case? Can you pls give me explicit difference of stationary state and non stationary?

Answer (score 2):

The state is called *stationary* if it is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian.

*Degeneracy* is a property of the spectrum of an operator. An eigenvalue is called degenerate if there are at least two linearly independent eigenstates with the same eigenvalue.

Also, when you hear the term degenerate without specifying which operator it applies to, usually it is assumed that this operator is the Hamiltonian.

So yes, degenerate states of the Hamiltonian are by definition stationary, and they have the same energy.

Comment: what if hamiltonian contains time dependent potential?

Comment: @AltuhaAbdu: Just think of the Stern-Gerlach experiment: What we found there is that by changing the Hamiltonian "quickly" the systems wave function can not adapt. Therefore, it is projected/decomposed  onto the new eigenbasis.

Comment: @AltuhaAbdu if the Hamiltonian changes with time, the eigenstate of $H(t_1)$ are not eigenstates of $H(t_2)$. Also, the eigenvalues change, too. There is no energy conservation.